Function increasing slower than any composition of logarithmic functions
I came up with a question of finding $f(n)$ it satisfies following property:
$$\forall k \in \mathbb{N} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{\log^k(n)} = 0 \;\mathrm{and} \lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = \infty,$$
where $\log^k(n)$ denotes $\log(\log(\cdots \log(n))\cdots)$ (iterated $k$ times.)
Equivalent formulation will be finding $g$ that goes infinity and
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{e^{\cdots^{e^n}}}}{g(n)} = 0$$
for arbitrary finite iterations of exponentials.
It seems that no elementary function satisfies the property. I've thought the function $g$ could be the busy beaver function, but I'm not sure since I don't know much about it. My question is:

Does there exist (computable) function that satisfies the property?
If exists, then is there any function that grows faster than arbitrary iterations of such function? Can this process be continued indefinitely?


These are many questions. Better focus on the first one.

Does this answer your question? Is there any nonconstant function that grows (at infinity) slower than all iterations of the (natural) logarithm? (Found using the search engine of MSE)

Thank you! Sorry for asking same question.
